# compilation problem appeared after formatting computer

Tags: python-3.x, compilation, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I'm currently working on a [project](https://github.com/ElinorG11/Intrcpt/blob/master/README.md) of a program to play a game similar to atari games (more information in the link) and I was debugging it and everything was running (didn't get any good results, but at-least it compiled and did something) and then I formatted my computer, and when I try to run my program again, it doesn't work, and give me some weird compilation problem which I cannot solve. perhaps anyone have an idea what can be wrong? [my code](https://github.com/ElinorG11/Intrcpt/blob/master/IntrcptNN%20using%20tensorflow) and the [full trace-back](https://github.com/ElinorG11/Intrcpt/blob/master/FullTraceback%20of%20compilation%20problem)

Thank you very much for you time and attention!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When formatting your PC you probably lost some installations you had.
Seems you have specifically lost the 'tensorflow_core.python' module. This is why the interpreter (not compiler) is giving you the error message. Try to install whatever you had before (anaconda ? jupiter ?)

Comment: thank you for your response, unfortunately, I've tried installing anaconda and jupiter again, but it didn't help (and I didn't have any other programs except from those two)